# Is this a valid way to show that the recursive sequence $x_n = x_{n-1} + \frac{1}{x_{n-1}^2}$ is unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

**I'm working through some analysis textbooks on my own, so I don't want the full answer. I'm only looking for a [hint](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11258/93114) on this problem.**

Rosenlicht's *Introduction to Analysis* asks me to prove that $x_n = x_{n-1} + \frac{1}{x_{n-1}^2}$, where $x_1 = 1$, is unbounded. I'm not sure how to approach this, but here's what I tried.

To save myself typing, I let $b := x_n$ and $a := x_{n-1}$.

Since $b > a > 1$ as $n \to \infty$, we know that

\begin{align}
b &> a \\
e^{\ln b} &> e^{\ln a} \\
\frac{e^{\ln b}}{e^{\ln a}} &> 1 \\
e^{\ln b - \ln a} &> 1
\end{align}

but I'm not sure where to go from here, or if this is even the right direction. I'm trying to show that $b - a > \ln b - \ln a$, because then I can say that the sequence is always growing faster than the logarithmic function, which I know is unbounded.

To show that $b - a > \ln b - \ln a$, I tried proof by contradiction. If $b - a \le \ln b - \ln a$, then $e^{b-a} \le e^ {\ln b - \ln a}$. Thus $\frac{e^b}{e^a} \le \frac{e^{\ln b}}{e^{\ln a}} = \frac{b}{a}$, and once again I'm not sure where to go.

I know that to show something is bounded, I need to show that $\exists M > 0$ s.t. $x_n < M, \forall n$. I know how to do that with non-recursive sequences, e.g. $x_n = f(n), n \in \mathbb{N}$ because it's just algebra, but I'm not sure how to go about this with a recursive sequence (once that I wasn't successful at putting in non-recursive terms).

Comment: One strong indication that you're barking up the wrong tree: none of your algebraic manipulations up to where you got have made any reference to the sequence definition you were given.  Now, there are sequences that _are_ increasing but bounded (for instance, $x_n=x_{n-1}+\frac1{n^2}$) so unless you use some specific property of *this* sequence, then you know your argument can't go anywhere.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I sort of figured I was barking up the wrong tree, and I'm still working at getting to the point where I'll recognize that faster. (It's great advice, too, that if I'm not using the properties of the sequence itself I'm probably not on the right path; thank you!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New one on me. Notice that the same sort of thing happens if we are adding something really tiny, for example
$$ y_{n+1} = y_n + \frac{1}{e^{y_n}};  $$ it just takes much longer to pass any given point.

So I wanted to emphasize that, we say the sequence is unbounded, how long does it take to get to specified points? This is the original example,
 $$ x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{1}{x_n^2}.  $$

Let us say that it takes one step to get us to $x_1 = 1.$

How long does it stay with $1 \leq x_n \leq 2?$ We are adding at least $1/4$ each time, so we reach or pass $2$ within four steps.

How long does it stay with $2 \leq x_n \leq 3?$ We are adding at least $1/9$ each time, so we reach or pass $3$ within another nine steps.

How long does it stay with $3 \leq x_n \leq 4?$ We are adding at least $1/16$ each time, so we reach or pass $4$ within another sixteen steps.

So, we are guaranteed to reach some positive integer $M$ within
$$ 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + \cdots + M^2 = \frac{1}{6} M (M+1)(2M+1)   $$
steps. Hope I remembered the sum correctly.

The same sort of argument works for the $y_n$ I gave above, but instead of adding the integers squared each time we add $e^w$ for $w-1 \leq y_n \leq w,$ so the sum to get to some $M$ is quite huge, finite geometric sum which can be calculated.

Rosenlicht was a good guy. My friend Dmitry was his student. I think, after his retirement, Rosy went to teach for a few years in Kenya.  Dmitry says also the Ivory Coast.

Answer (score 4):

Hint #1: The sequence is monotone increasing.  If it were bounded, it would have a limit.  What property would that limit satisfy?

Hint #2: That limit would satisfy $$L=L+\frac{1}{L^2}$$

However no $L$ satisfies this equation.

Comment: The limit would be the supremum. I'll work with that and see what I get.

Comment: Sure, but what algebraic property would that limit $L$ satisfy?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're thinking of, unless it's just the definition of the limit in that for any $\epsilon > 0, \exists N \ge 1$ s.t. $|x_i - L| < \epsilon$ when $i \ge N$.

Comment: What algebraic property specific to this particular sequence?

Comment: All that springs to mind at the moment is that since $L > x_n, \forall n$, then $\frac{1}{x^2_{n-1}} = x_n - x_{n-1} < L - x_{n-1} < L$, which I *think* is helpful because $x_n$ is strictly monotonically increasing, so for any $L$, we can eventually find an element in the sequence such that the inequality $\frac{1}{x^2_{n-1}} \ge L$.

Comment: A different way of looking at vadim's hint: if the sequence has a limit, then of necessity $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n-x_{n-1})=0$ (why?) -- can you see why this is causes a contradiction?

Comment: I know that $\lim_n(x_n-x_{n-1})=0$ because if this wasn't true, then the sequence would converge to multiple limits (because the limit of the difference is the difference of the limits, and $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$ are the same sequence. I still don't see why this causes a contradiction, though, so I must be missing the algebraic property in question.

Comment: But since $x_n - x_{n-1} = \frac{1}{x^2_{n-1}}$, doesn't this have a limit of $0$ anyway? Maybe I'm confusing it with $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: @Michael I think you are.  Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=L$.  Then what is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{x_n^2}$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{L^2}$? Maybe I need to take a break from this for an hour or so. I feel like I'm just getting more confused.

Comment: @Michael That's understandable - but you should be able to put together everything in the last few comments here...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\{x_n\}$ is a bounded sequence, that is $0<x_n \leq M$ for some $M$. Then:

$x_n = (x_n-x_{n-1})+(x_{n-1}-x_{n-2})+\cdots +(x_2-x_1)+x_1 = \dfrac{1}{x_{n-1}^2}+\dfrac{1}{x_{n-2}^2}+ \cdots +\dfrac{1}{x_1^2}>\dfrac{1}{M^2}+\dfrac{1}{M^2}+\cdots +\dfrac{1}{M^2}=\dfrac{n-1}{M^2}$. If we select $n$ be such that $n > M^3+1$, then $x_n > M$, and it shows $\{x_n\}$ is not bounded.

Answer (score 0):

It's straightforward to show by induction that the sequence is strictly positive and strictly increasing. Therefore the sequence converges if and only if it is bounded above. Suppose there exists $M$ such that $x_n<M$ for all $n$. Then $\frac1{x_{n-1}}>\frac1M$ so $\frac1{x_{n-1}^2}>\frac1{M^2}$. But this implies that $x_n-x_{n-1}=\frac1{x_{n-1}^2}>\frac1{M^2}$ for all $n$, so $\{x_n\}$ cannot converge (take $\varepsilon <\frac1{M^2}$). This is a contradiction, so we conclude that $\{x_n\}$ is not bounded.